# Is it possible to remove variables with a certain pattern from a datatable or list?

Tags: r

For example if I have a list which contains: `"a"`, `"ab"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, `"ad"` as variables.

Is it possible to remove all variables which contain an `"a"`, without writing every single variable down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `grep` or `grepl` could help

```
> grep("a",v,value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
[1] "b" "c"
```

or

```
> v[!grepl("a",v)]
[1] "b" "c"
```

**Data**

```
v <- c("a","ab","b","c","ad")
```

Answer (score 2):

“variables” are conventionally called “names” in R.

So if you want to remove them from a list-like structure, you can manipulate its `names`, and then subset the list with the resulting vector of names.

```
x = x[grep('a', names(x), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)]
```

Or, using `grepl` instead:

```
x = x[! grepl('a', names(x))]
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `str_subset`

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(v, "a", negate = TRUE)
#[1] "b" "c"
```

#### data

```
v <- c("a","ab","b","c","ad")
```